# ASP.NET MVC CORE 2.0 sending data from DOM to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I need a strategy here.

In webforms I used a `<asp:HiddenField>` inside an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` to send back and forth data from DOM to SQL Server.

The great feature of this approach was to avoid a page refresh (**!important**)

In ASP.NET MVC CORE 2.0, there is no `<asp:UpdatePanel>` and I understand I have to send data back and forth from view to controller.

Where do I find a working example, simple enough for a beginner with ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0? I am working on this for a whole long day and so far everything I saw was a ton of samples extremely far more complex than the old `<asp:HiddenField>` > `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are wanting to update part of the screen with new information without reloading the whole screen.

The following jQuery JavaScript code is an example of calling a controller action and returning some data and then stuffing it into a DOM element with a class of result:

```
   $('#CategoryID').on("change", function () {
        var categoryId = $('#CategoryID').val();
        $.get("/Products/UpdateSubCategories/" + categoryId , function (data) {
            console.log("Data: " + data);
            $('.result').html(data);
        });
    })
```

This JavaScript fires when the element with an ID of CategoryID changes.

Here's the example of the controller action:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSubCategories(int id)
    {
        if (id==0)
        {
            NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["SubCategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.SubCategories.Where(s => s.CategoryId == id).OrderBy(s => s.SubCategoryName), "Id", "SubCategoryName");
        return PartialView();

    }
```

Note also created a Partial View that is used to create the required HTML for a Select List.

```
@model Namespace.Models.Products


<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="SubCategoryId" class="control-label"></label><span style="color:red"> *</span>
    <select asp-for="SubCategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SubCategoryId">
        <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="SubCategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me. In the meanwhile I had figured it out by myself, however your answer is much leaner so I have revised my code based on it. Thanks.